# Updating DynamoDB in a Lambda Stripe Webhook

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, stripe-payments

I have an application that is succesfully accepting a payment in Stripe and then calling a webhook through Api Gateway and Lambda. I would like the webhook to update 'userTickets' in my DynamoDB Table. The webhook is succeeding in the Stripe dashboard but there is no change to my DynamoDB table.

```
const endpointSecret = process.env.STRIPE_ENDPOINT_SECRET

var express = require("express")
var bodyParser = require("body-parser")
var awsServerlessExpressMiddleware = require("aws-serverless-express/middleware")
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
AWS.config.update({ region: 'ap-southeast-2' });
var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()


// declare a new express app
var app = express()
// Add raw body to req params for Stripe signature check
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    verify: function (req, res, buf) {
      req.rawBody = buf.toString()
    },
  })
)
app.use(awsServerlessExpressMiddleware.eventContext())

// Enable CORS for all methods
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  )
  next()
})

app.post("/webhook", async function (req, res) {
  // Check Stripe signature
  const sig = req.headers["stripe-signature"]

  let event
  try {
    event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(req.rawBody, sig, endpointSecret)
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(400).send(`Webhook Error: ${err.message}`)
  }

  switch (event.type) {
    case "checkout.session.completed":
      console.log(event);
      console.log(
        `Payment checkout session for ${req.body.data.object.client_reference_id} was successful!`
      );


       //Create tickets in db
       const params = {
        TableName: "Users",
        Key: {
           PK: "User#85b17436-76c8-4ca5-9dbe-3a4126d94dfb",
           SK: "User#85b17436-76c8-4ca5-9dbe-3a4126d94dfb"
        },
        UpdateExpression: `SET userTickets = :tickets`,
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":tickets": "100"
        },
        ReturnValues:"UPDATED_NEW"
     };
     console.log("Updating the item...");
     docClient.update(params, function(err, data) {
       if (err) {
         console.error("Unable to update item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
       } else {
         console.log("UpdateItem succeeded:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
       }
       context.done(null, event);
     });

      break;
    default:
      // Unexpected event type
      return res.status(400).end()
  }

  // Return a response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  res.json({ received: true })
})

// Export the app object. When executing the application local this does nothing. However,
// to port it to AWS Lambda we will create a wrapper around that will load the app from
// this file
module.exports = app
```

Is there something wrong with the way I am updating DDB? I can't find any resources about calling DDB within a lambda webhook.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have quite a few log statements in your code. It would be helpful to see those logs to determine what is happening.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Express middleware you're using but I would not use context.done for async Lambda functions and I would use the async/promise variant of the DynamoDB calls e.g. `const data = await docClient.update(params)`

Comment: Like Mark B suggested, I'd also recommend looking at the logs to see if anything funky is going on with the code that you have.

Comment: I've had a look at the logs. They are all outputting what you would expect from a working function, including the 'payment checkout session for *** was successful.

Comment: Jarmod - When I remove context.done and add your line my webhook comes up with a 502 error in Stripe. Are you suggesting the line of code you included to go where the contest.done is?

Comment: Did you find any solution?